# How can move n characters from front of the string to the end continuously every time I press the button?

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I'm trying to move the first char of the string to the end every time I press the button.

My logic seems to only display the first output again and again after I press the button.

```
string input = "";
string manipulated = "";
int initial;

input = txtInput.Text;

if (txtInput.Text == String.Empty)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Textbox is empty, please input a string.");
}
else 
{
        for (initial = 1; initial < input.Length; initial++)
        {
            manipulated += input[initial];
        }
        manipulated += input[0];
        lblOutput.Text = manipulated.ToString();
        input = manipulated;
        manipulated = "";
}
```

E.g.  if I enter "1234" in the text box and press the button, my output should be "2341", then after I hit the button again, the output should move to "3412" .. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple example of Basics String operations:

```
private void ManipulateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string input = InputTxt.Text; // Read the text from you Textbox in Windos form
        if (input == string.Empty)
        {
            return;
        }
        string temp = input[0].ToString(); // Create a temp for the first char(toString) from you input
        input = input.Remove(0,1); // Remove (from you input) At Index 0 (the idex from fist char in string) 1 time) 
        input += temp; //add the firs item from you input at the end of string
        InputTxt.Text = input; // prin the result in the Textbox back.
    }
```

You can see the example [SimpleStringOperation](https://github.com/gtsonkov/SimpleStringOperation)

Comment: this it very helpful. however i want my output to be at lblOutput, meaning the lblOutput.Text should continuously change every time i press the button and not the Input.Text
i can use this as reference. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Thank You soooo much @gtsonkov this really help me a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

You can Improve your code by another solution using [Substring Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8)

Create a new variable called `_number` and set the value to 1

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    private int _number = 1; 
    // ....
}
```

Then in Button event, you can replace your code with this code

```
    private void BtnMoveText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtInput.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"TextBox is empty, please input a string.");
            return;
        }
        if (_number > txtInput.TextLength)
            _number = 1;
        lblOutput.Text = txtInput.Text.Substring(_number) + txtInput.Text.Substring(0, _number);
        _number++;

        #region ** Depending on Microsoft **

         /*
           Substring(Int32)
             (Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and continues to the end of the string.)
           Parameters
               startIndex Int32
               The zero-based starting character position of a substring in this instance.
      .......................
           Substring(Int32, Int32) 
            (Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and has a specified length..)
           Parameters
               startIndex Int32
               The zero-based starting character position of a substring in this instance.
               length Int32                
               The number of characters in the substring.
       */
        #endregion

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're taking your OUTPUT and placing it in a Label...but continuing to take your INPUT from the TextBox which **hasn't changed**...thus the same result each time.

Simply change:

```
lblOutput.Text = manipulated.ToString();
```

To:

```
txtInput.Text = manipulated;
```