# Is there any way to move the first letter to end?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I'm trying to move the *first letter* of a word to the *end* on C#.
User will enter a word.

And the first letter of the word will go to the end of the word.

**Example:**

**Input:** `hello`

**Output:** `elloh`

Comment: Written any code yourself yet?

Comment: please show us your effort

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56301414/how-can-move-n-characters-from-front-of-the-string-to-the-end-continuously-every

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can move n characters from front of the string to the end continuously every time i press the button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56301414/how-can-move-n-characters-from-front-of-the-string-to-the-end-continuously-every)

Comment: `string result = source.Substring(1) + source.Substring(0, 1);`

Comment: You should show us what you have already tried... Otherwise how can we help you?

Comment: It is good exercise, you should try it? Definitely you will learn something good if you do it by yourself

Comment: if you feel an answer solved your problem, please don't forget to mark it as accepted by clicking the gray checkmark beside the answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
var str = "hello";
var result = string.Join("", str.Skip(1)) + str[0];
```

However you need to add the following to your using directives first:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try a simple `string` manipulation with a help of [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8):

```
 input.Substring(0, 1) - to get the 1st letter (or just input[0])
 input.Substring(1)    - to get all letters except 1st - all letters starting from 1
```

**Code:**

```
 string input = "hello";

 // To be on the safe side, let's check if user input is an empty string
 string output = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) 
   ? input.Substring(1) + input.Substring(0, 1) // or input.Substring(1) + input[0]
   : input; // or throw exception (C# 7.0+)
```

*Linq* version (just for reference); let's use `??` and `?.` operators in case we are given `null` or empty (`""`) strings:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ... 

  string output = string.Concat(input?.Skip(1) ?? "") + input?.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

```cs
string output = input.Substring(1) + input[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string MoveChar(this string text, int oldIndex, int newIndex)
{
    try
    {
        var chars = new List<Char>( text.ToCharArray(0, text.Length));
        var value = chars[oldIndex];
        chars.RemoveAt(oldIndex);
        chars.Insert(newIndex,value);
        return new string(chars.ToArray());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```